# Git branching & local changes

Tags: git

We cannot switch branches in Git without committing the changes or stashing them. What is the bigger picture behind this and why did Linus take this approach while designing Git?

If switching branches cause local changes showing up across branches, What is the point in branches as they are expected work in isolation ?

Comment: You *can* switch branches without first committing: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452. But: why do you claim that branches "are expected to work in isolation" in the first place? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452

Comment: I agree with @torek. I'd like to understand what you mean by "work in isolation".

Comment: Ever used Pythons virtual envs?  Branches can be thought the same until you deliberately want to merge them.

Comment: @itsneo: a branch is simply a tracking of a history of changes, of which there can be many separate histories side by side. It is not an entire environment. You should read more about the fundamental model of Git and perhaps it'll make more sense.

Comment: @siride I hear you and understand the what it is, but the question is revolving more on WHY.

Comment: @itsneo: you mean why did they design Git that way? That's not really a question I can answer. I can answer that *if* you understand how branches and objects and heads work under the hood, it'll be clear why branches don't do what you think they do. As to why that was designed, I literally cannot answer that.

Answer (score -2):

> We cannot switch branches in Git without committing the changes or stashing them.

Actually you can force switching branch, but then you lose any uncommitted changes on current branch. It should be very unusual if you want to lose your current work just to switching branch. Why not commit it first to current branch, or at least `stash` the changes so you can come back?

Anyway to force switching branch, you can:

1)

```
git checkout -f <new_branch>  // will lose any uncommitted changes on <old_branch>
```

or,

2)

```
git reset --hard <commit-hash-id-of-new-branch>  // will lose any uncommitted changes on <old_branch>
```

Comment: The question is not to learn about how to switch, Instead to understand the design between such a reality :(

Comment: If you switch branches, you do not lose uncommitted changes. They stay there and Git attemps to apply them to the new branch, potentially resulting in a conflict.

Comment: @siride even without `stash` ?

Comment: @siride: Normally if there would be a conflict, Git simply refuses the `git checkout`. You can use `-f` as @artm suggests to overwrite, or `-m` to request that Git attempt to merge the files.

Comment: That's the worst part, why would git apply changes? It's like merging just switching branche,  that's not what the user will usually intend for.

Comment: @itsneo not sure what design you are asking about. It's common to any version control that you save/commit your work before changing branch

Comment: Imagine a scenario I'm working on 1 project in 2 features and 2 bugs and another buddies cherry picked bug. My list of branches grow up quickly as git encourages branching often but switching between branches I need to remember the stashes of each(whether I did or not). I don't want to commit something until something is worth committing.

Comment: @siride you said "do not lose uncommitted changes" - does that work without `stash`??